# Query that computes user normalized rank

Tags: support, data-explorer

Consider this python code:

```
from datetime import datetime


# q1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498770/why-does-instance-of-object-foo-is-instance-of-object-foo-evaluate-false/50498830#50498830
# q2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206403/why-does-a-value-of-an-enum-with-a-fixed-underlying-type-of-char-resolve-to-fct
# q3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha
questions = [
    (datetime(2012, 6, 27), 21458),
    (datetime(2013, 6, 8), 24),
    (datetime(2010, 4, 18), 104)
]


def elapsed_days(d1, d2):
    return (d1 - d2).days


def upvotes_per_day(tpl):
    return elapsed_days(datetime.now(), tpl[0]) / tpl[1]

# Days SO has been running
max_days = elapsed_days(datetime.now(), datetime(2008, 9, 15))

# Heuristic: Let's assume this value has been computed using SO's database
max_upvotes_per_day = 100


def question_weight(tpl):
    return upvotes_per_day(tpl) / max_upvotes_per_day


weights = [question_weight(q) for q in questions]
print(sum(weights) / float(len(weights)))
```

Basically the algorithm goes like this:

**a)** Compute elapsed days of each user's question/answer

**b)** Compute maximum number of upvotes_per_day of all users questions/answers (this would be ranked 1). <== HEURISTIC

**c)** Normalize each user's question/answer elapsed days using the value computed at b)

**d)** Average all weights computed at c)

How can I create a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) that translates the above algorithm to compute the user's rank (using either user questions or answers)?

Comment: People who are voting to close this, please take a little more notice to the question - it's not a programming question that belongs else where :)

Answer (score 4):

I think I managed to do this more or less, but I doubt it produces the results you expect. For Stack Overflow answers, [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) should be ranked at the top of the list, but he doesn't. Instead, this ranking favors new users who have a handful of posts (and often just a single one which hit the Hot Network Questions list).

First, the maximum score (corrected for age) is [30.9 for questions and 27 for answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866549/maximum-score-per-day-per-post-type). But we don't need that to compute a rank, when all we do is comparing users. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866550/users-by-average-score-per-post-type) does that; you'll need to choose a value for `PostTypeId`, either 1 for questions and 2 for answers:

[image]
[image]

It's rather obvious that these users won't stay at the top of the list; in a few weeks, they'll be replaced with new users who then have nothing but a few recent good-scoring posts.

Comment: Interesting, before validating I'll try to understand the whole query first. So maybe the heuristic of considering rank=1 to the max number max user upvotes_per_day isn't good afterall. What about max days Stackoverflow has been running, how could we use that as a weight factor for the formula? For the time being, +1 . And yeah, you're right, the formula should give Jon skeet rank 1 for sure. In any case, this was a naive ocurrence of mine, all I'm trying to do is trying to get rid of the whole noise introduced by the popularity factor, that's pretty much

Comment: There are two main problems; a post will usually get most votes the first few days after it has been posted, and then accumulate upvotes in a slower pace over time. The second phase could be linear and 'upvotes_per_day' is a crude metric but it might makes sense for that phase. The first phase is unpredictable with HNQ and all that. The second problem is that some users just get 'lucky' and make a single successful post.

Comment: I've noticed your query isn't using the proposed algorithm from my question. If you take a look, my algorithm intends to provide normalized ranks [0-1]. That's what steps b) & c) are for. That said, I've realized few thing my algorithm won't take into consideration and that is the number of questions/answers per user (how much content they provided). That should be also a relevant factor (normalized), otherwise users with few posts will become ranked very high. Take a look to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9953551/peter), just one nice question has made it rank #1 .

Comment: Here's the [normalized popularity](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866737/users-normalized-popularity), maybe that could also be introduced as a weight factor in order to get a better metric