# Query to compute user content traffic

Tags: support, data-explorer

Trying to create a query to view the total amount of user's content traffic. That is, how many views the user questions/answers has received, my first attempt has been:

```
Select Id As [Post Link], CreationDate, Score, ViewCount
From Posts
Where PostTypeId=2 --Answers
    And OwnerUserId=##UserId##
Order By Score desc
```

When I run this query with my user id all ViewCount columns are NULL, why is that?

PS: This question is related to [Query that computes user normalized rank](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311657/query-that-computes-user-normalized-rank) as I believe the user traffic could explain some facts about users popularity and help to create a proper query to measure **user performance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly view the ViewCount of the answers, based on the ParentId you can link to the Questions and the viewcount of the question is the answer's viewcount.

So the query below will give the ViewCount of the posts you have answered:

```
SELECT Q.Id AS [Post Link], A.CreationDate, A.Score, Q.ViewCount,
       COALESCE(Q.ViewCount/NULLIF(A.Score, 0), 0) AS Traffic
FROM Posts Q
JOIN Posts A ON A.ParentId = Q.Id
WHERE A.PostTypeId = 2 AND A.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
ORDER BY A.Score DESC
```

Comment: Cool, thx, so... how'd you go about computing the user performance based on traffic & score? That is, sum(score)/ sum(views). The first test `cast(ViewCount/Score as float)` is giving me `Divide by zero error encountered.` exception, any idea to prevent this?

Comment: You can use `COALESCE(Q.ViewCount/NULLIF(A.Score, 0), 0)` to avoid the `Divide by zero error`

Comment: Great, btw, I guess I've got a typo in my previous comment. As I think the quality factor would be something like "score/ViewCount". Take a look to this [https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866756/user-answers-sorted-by-quality](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866756/user-answers-sorted-by-quality), this one gives results while this other one [https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866803/user-questions-sorted-by-quality](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866803/user-questions-sorted-by-quality) does not, why?

Comment: For the Question's Viewcount (PostTypeId = 1), there is no need of the sub query. Your query in the original post will work by changing the PostTypeId = 1. Also I have modified the query in the answer with JOINS, the previous one is not returning the correct data

Comment: Try your query's answer with [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656) id 22656, any workaround about this?

Comment: Adding `TOP` will work, like `SELECT TOP 30000`. Since he answered 34,146 answers in SO, up to `SELECT TOP 34100` it doesn't throw any `The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan` error.

Comment: Ok, cool, your answer provides enough information to continue digging about this topic by myself. Remaining is using the whole information to come up with a good equation that measures a proper user "performance factor". Thx